# Sharing NSURLsession delegate implementation among view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, nsurlsession, delegation

In my iOS app, many ViewControllers will need to send/receive data from a server based on user input and actions.  I am going to use NSURLSession for all my networking activities.  But I don't want to make every ViewController conform to the NSURLSession delegate
 protocol and repeat all the methods.

I see two solutions

- Create a class that conforms to the NSURLSession delegate
  protocol.  Other classes create an instance of this class and use its methods to send/receive data from the server.  The reuse of the class handling all the networking will be done using singleton design pattern by overloading its init method so that only instance of it is created.

  - Disadvantage of this approach seems to be that having singletons make its tough to create unit tests that completely gets functionality of each class isolated form others. I.e.Suppose an error only happens because viewcontroler1 asked "shared class" to send a particular message followed viewcontroller 2 asked it send some other message.  Then it is not possible to catch this using unit tests.
- Subclass of the UIViewController that implements the methods and subclass my ViewControllers of of this.

  - One issue here is that if I have different kinds of views in app, then I need to create subclass for each type of ViewController with NSURL session delegate methods.  And I have to carefully assign the delegate object from method to method.  When I look at it, I think this approach also has the same unit-testing problem as approach 1.

I would appreciate any comments on
1. Approaches others have used in similar situation
2. Pros/cons of above approaches (including the 2 I have listed above).  I realize this may be a bit subjective, but IMHO getting good advice on design patterns is as important as (or even more important than) answers to what is wrong with my code or which API to use to solve problem X

Comment: "Create a class that conforms to the NSURLSession delegate protocol". Make it a singleton if only one connection can be active at a time and/or if the connection should continue after the view controller has been destroyed. Otherwise each view controller could use an individual instance of the class.

Comment: Thanks, since user may send a file and then either a) put the app in background or b) move to another screen in the app, I thought its best to take the singleton approach.  But I saw some scary stuff about singleton's being a bad thing.  IMHO, the testability issues that are sassed seem applicable to other approaches too.   So, I think I might just go with this.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done this in the past is:

1) Created a class that contained a NSURLSession object 
    @interface CustomSession : NSURLSessionDelegate
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSession *mySession;

2) In the CustomSession init method initialize mySession, set delegate to self.

3) Implemented desired NSURLSession delegate methods in CustomSession.

4) Use block methods (optional, but I prefer them)

5) Decide whether you want to use CustomSession as a singleton or instantiate it every time you need it. You can actually do both just define init methods accordingly.

```
+ (CustomSession *)session
{
    //Singleton
}

+ (instancetype) newClient{
    //normal init method}
```

6) As for unit testing, you could have a weak pointer in CustomSession to the parent VC (as you pointed out this would work if you're not using a Singleton).

Quick suggestion: Use AFNetworking, will simplify your life. For example I use AFHTTPSessionManager and the corresponding block methods provided:
    [self GET:detailsURL parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)

Comment: Thanks @codinpora.  Since user may send/request file & a) put the app in background or b) move to another screen in the app, won't I need singleton approach.  Do you see any way around it?   I was thinking about AFNetworking but also wanted to learn the SDK the "hard way" in case there are flexibilities that AFNetworking does not expose.   With AFNetworking I see that you only need to give blocks for what to execute upon "success" or "Failure", how do they handle things like user moves from one screen to another?  Will adopting it be any better in being able to write better unit-tested code?